# Parallel iteration over boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing

I'm working with such a code:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> final_results;
std::size_t pos = bitset.find_first();
while(boost::dynamic_bitset<>::npos != pos)
{
  //do some time consuming stuff

  if(results_are_nice)
    final_results.push_back(pos);

  pos = bitset.find_next(pos);
}
```

I'd like to parallelize this loop. Time consuming stuff is a real bottleneck. I know there are some ready to go solutions for "for loop" paralellization. But here I need synchronization at access to final_results and iteration over boost::dynamic_bitset is a little more sophisticated.

How should I proceed? Iterate over the whole bitset, store indices of true values in a vector and parallelize iteration over that vector?

Comment: what did you try? and did you in fact measure that this loop was a bottleneck?

Comment: Yes. It is a bottle neck, because inside a loop as a "time consuming stuff" I perform several file operations(read only), which has to indicate if "pos" should be included into a final result.

Comment: File operations will probably not improve with parallel threading unless you're using a SSD or RAID. The bottleneck on disk files is almost always the disk.